# Where is custom.css in the generated html file from nbconvert?

Tags: html, css, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I am using nbconvert to convert my jupyter notebook to html by

> jupyter nbconvert my.ipynb --to html

Then it says:

> [NbConvertApp] Converting notebook my.ipynb to html
> [NbConvertApp] Writing 407497 bytes to my.html

Then in the generated `my.html`, I can see it requires `custom.css`:

```
<!-- Custom stylesheet, it must be in the same directory as the html file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">

<!-- Loading mathjax macro -->
<!-- Load mathjax -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/latest.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML"></script>
    <!-- MathJax configuration -->
    <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
        tex2jax: {
            inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
            displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
            processEscapes: true,
            processEnvironments: true
        },
        // Center justify equations in code and markdown cells. Elsewhere
        // we use CSS to left justify single line equations in code cells.
        displayAlign: 'center',
        "HTML-CSS": {
            styles: {'.MathJax_Display': {"margin": 0}},
            linebreaks: { automatic: true }
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Info:
nbconvert version is `5.6.1`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">` effectively causes customized CSS styling rules to be included if the file `custom.css` exists in the same directory.

In case you want some customized CSS styling rules for displaying the generated html. You can add a file `custom.css` with those rules, in the same directory as the html file.

This is not a mandatory requirement. It is fine to not include such a file if you don't want any customized styling rules. The default CSS rules in generated HTML file will still work.

Comment: The use case here is I convert notebook to html which will be served to a browser. The issue is If I return the html file to a browser, that browser will try to fetch the `css` file automatically. I am trying to avoid such redundant fetch because there is no css file existing on server side.

Comment: I'd suggest that you remove that line from the generated html files yourself. If there are many html files you can automate  this easily (on linux) with something like `sed -i '/link.*custom\.css/d' generated_html/*.html`

Comment: This is the solution I decided to use. My use case is not performance centric so I can take this hacky way to serve the htmls. But if your use case is more performance centric, use Amal K's solution.

Answer (score 3):

If your sole problem is this line: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">`, you can modify the template file and write a custom HTML exporter:

Navigate to the source directory of nbconvert. Go to `./templates/html/`. There will be a file called `full.tpl`. This serves as the template for your HTML file. Open the file with a text editor and delete the `<link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">` line.
Save the file with a `.tpl` extension (`fullcustom.tpl`). Make sure you save it in the same directory as `full.tpl`.

The next step is to either write a custom exporter class in Python(recommended). You have to inherit the `HTMLExporter` class defined in `./exporters/html.py`. You can follow the procedure described here: https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/external_exporters.html

Now, if you do not want to spend the time doing this, a quick "kludge" would be to actually modify the `HTMLExporter` class. Create a copy of the `html.py` file if you want as it is being modified. Open `./exporters/html.py` and find the following method in the `HTMLExporter` class:

```
@default('template_file')
    def _template_file_default(self):
        return 'full.tpl'
```

Change `return full.tpl` to the name you saved your modified version of `full.tpl` with (`fullcustom.tpl`).